# How to find the escape sequence for `Shift + PageUp`/`Shift + PageDown`?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, tmux, scrolling

How can I find the escape sequence for `Shift + PageUp`/`Shift + PageDown`?

I googled and tried a few suggestions, but what always happens is that the screen scrolls up/down when I press this, or nothing gets printed.

I'm trying to get the escape sequence, so that I can assign it to the PageUp/PageDown function in *Tmux*, when I'm in a TTY/virtual console. As you might know, recent *Linux* kernels have removed this functionality.

If it's relevant, some other `Shift`-related bindings I'm using in my terminal *WezTerm*:

```
{key='UpArrow', mods='SHIFT', action=wezterm.action{SendString='\x1b[a'}},
{key='DownArrow', mods='SHIFT', action=wezterm.action{SendString='\x1b[b'}},
{key='LeftArrow', mods='SHIFT', action=wezterm.action{SendString='\x1b[d'}},
{key='RightArrow', mods='SHIFT', action=wezterm.action{SendString='\x1b[c'}},
```

Just giving an escape sequence that's in spirit with the above escape sequences is fine too.

Comment: Have you tried `xev`?

Comment: You could run this: https://termbin.com/3z1r

Comment: @ibuprofen Thank you! Works after adding `disable_default_key_bindings = true,` to *WezTerm*'s config. Can accept that as an answer. They show for me as `\E[5;2~`, `\E[6;2~`.

Comment: Nothing wrong with bringing up vi, go into insert mode, hit ctrl-v, then the key you are interested in.

Comment: @Bib Ah that reminds me, in fact `showkey -a` works already, when I add `disable_default_key_bindings = true,` to *WezTerm*'s config. I don't have *Vi* installed.

Comment: Yes, `showkey -a` is a viable alternative. As well as `sed -n l` (that is lower case L). For this case the minimal script was merely a hack for nicety's sake :P,  - feel free to answer your own Q.

Answer (score 1):

To find this, I first suppress my terminal emulator *WezTerm*'s default key bindings in `~/.wezterm.lua`, so they get passed onto the terminal:

```
local wezterm = require 'wezterm';

return {
  disable_default_key_bindings = true,
  ...
}
```

Then I can use the following to get my escape sequences:

```
$ showkey -a

Press any keys - Ctrl-D will terminate this program

^[[5;2~          27 0033 0x1b
         91 0133 0x5b
         53 0065 0x35
         59 0073 0x3b
         50 0062 0x32
        126 0176 0x7e
^[[6;2~          27 0033 0x1b
         91 0133 0x5b
         54 0066 0x36
         59 0073 0x3b
         50 0062 0x32
        126 0176 0x7e
^D        4 0004 0x04
```

So they are:

- `Shift + PageUp`: `\e[5;2~`
- `Shift + PageDown`: `\e[6;2~`